# Is there a way to open the image in google colab once it is saved on the disk while using C++ opencv?

Tags: image, opencv, google-colaboratory, imshow

I tried all the opencv methods to save image, but the image is not being saved on the drive. However, they are saved on the disk. How can I show the image that is being created?

I tried:

`imshow("Source Image", im_src);`

Answer (score 0):

Oh... Just found out how... After you save the image:

`imwrite("matches.jpg", imMatches);`

it is being saved in the disk; hence, there is a 3 line button in the top left corner of the colab named **Table of contents**. Press that and then press the folder image. There are all the files on the disk. Simple double click on the image **will open the image**.